# How do I create a function which reverses an int list in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a type intlist:

```
type intlist = Nil | Cons of int * intlist
```

and I'd now like to write a function that reverses the list. I have no real idea how to go about this. in class, our prof defined a function within a function, I believe, but I don't have the solution with me. How would one do this, simply? I would appreciate if we can keep the coding rather rudimentary, seeing as I'm relatively new to this.

So far, I only have

```
let reverse (l : intlist) : intlist = 
  match l with
    Nil -> Nil
  | Cons(a, Nil) -> Cons(a, Nil)
```

This is how I tend to create these kinds of functions, so I've written the trivial part (which granted, may not actually be what I need to start with). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't have to define a function within a function, you can just define the helper function on the top level and call it from `reverse`. Keeps the syntax simple for a start. (You still can make it a local function later once everything works).

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough. Is there any way of doing this with one single function?

Comment: Try with a function that takes two parameters: one for the elements that have already been reversed (that were in front of the current list), and one for the current list (i.e. the rest that are still to be reversed).

Comment: No, I don't think there's a way to do this with a single function (without using builtins, without using mutability - without all the hard stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need a helper function, since for the reversing you need to build another list, so you need a function that will recurse into one list, while building another list, i.e., that has two arguments. In fact, this helper function is called `rev_append` and it is appending a reversed contents of one list to another. But let's try to make it using a helper function defined in the scope of the `rev` function:

```
 let rev xs =
   let rec loop xs ys = match xs with
     | Nil -> ys
     | Cons (x,xs) -> loop xs (Cons (x,ys)) in
   loop xs Nil
```

So, to reverse a list we just take each element of a list and put it into another list. Since list behaves like a stack we are getting the reversed list for free. It is like Hanoi towers, when you pick elements from one list (tower) and put them to another, they will end up in a reversed order.